# Formatting lists with the column command in *nix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, formatting

I'm trying to format a list of entries in bash, and am using the `column` command. However, the `-t` option defaults to using any whitespace as a delimiter, which does not work for the data I have (it contains spaces and tabs). I can't figure out how to get the `-s` flag to specify a newline character as the sole column delimiter.

Comment: can you post some sample input & output?

Comment: Note that `column` is available on Linux (and on Mac OS X 10.7.4).  It is not necessarily available on other variants of Unix; it is not standardized by POSIX, for example.

Comment: If you want 3 columns of output, `pr -l 1 -t -3` will get very close to what you wanted `column` to produce.  For N columns, change the 3 to N; to specify a width, add `-w 120` or whatever.

Comment: `pr -l 1 -t -3` worked perfectly! Thanks, Jonathan! I think I don't quite understand the `column` command as illustrated below by ruakh.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In theory, to specify a newline, you can use the `$'...'` notation, which is just like `'...'` except that it supports C-style escape-sequences:

```
column -t -s $'\n' list-of-entries.txt
```

However, I don't really understand the purpose of this. A newline is the row delimiter, so a column-delimiter of `$'\n'` is equivalent to not having any column-delimiter at all:

```
column -t -s '' list-of-entries.txt
```

which means that the input will be treated as having only one column; so it's equivalent to not using `column` at all:

```
cat list-of-entries.txt
```

It seems like you actually *don't* want to use the `-t` flag, because the purpose of the `-t` flag is to ensure that each line of input becomes one line of output, and it doesn't sound like that's what you want. I'm guessing you want this:

```
column list-of-entries.txt
```

which will treat each line of `list-of-entries.txt` as a value to be put in one cell of the table that `column` outputs.

Comment: Great explanation with fully understanding of the real problem that the questioner encountered!

Comment: You hit it right on the head! Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 6):

This works to output a pretty print version of a tab delimited file

```
column -t -s $'\t' list-of-entries.txt
```